What fallacy is this inversion of Gambler's Fallacy?
I just found what I have forever considered to be "Gambler's fallacy fallacy" appears to be not it. It seems "Gambler's fallacy fallacy" is actually belief that probability of a series of events is the same as probability of the last of them (crossing a 4-lane road is exactly as dangerous as crossing a 1-lane one)
The variant I was using went like this:

if you toss a coin and get 5 heads in a row, believing the chance for heads is anything but 50/50 is a gambler's fallacy.

if you toss a coin and get 100 heads in a row, believing the chance for heads is still 50/50, rather than that the game is rigged, is a gambler's fallacy fallacy.


The fallacy stems from disregarding statistical evidence that contradicts our initial assumptions and blaming on luck or accident what most likely was not.
Apparently this isn't named gambler's fallacy fallacy. So what is it? Does it have a name?

Wikipedia calls a belief that after a long streak of tails another tail is more likely (due to suspected rigging) "reverse position", citing O'Neill-Puza, who call it "reverse gambler's belief". They describe it as a "rational and Bayesian conclusion", but do not name its (fallacious) denial anything in particular.

I've met Monte Carlo fallacy (bet opposite of the streak, "overdue") and Hot Hand fallacy (bet same as streak, baseless suspicion of bias) but they supposedly differ from gambler's fallacy and aren't just its sub-variants, though I didn't quite catch, how.

I asked basically the same question three years ago on CrossValidated. The answer I liked the most was "ludic fallacy"

Nice!  If I could toss you my "Accepted Answer" check mark, I would.

Tossed that for you. :) Right on time as it JUST came up on Twitter!

I don't know of any specific name for that fallacy, but perhaps: An argument from ignorance, using the gambler's fallacy as the cloak?  Both the gambler's fallacy and the "gambler's fallacy fallacy" are misunderstandings of probability itself, while the fallacy you describe has to do with faith in the "honesty" of the coin being flipped, so to speak, but doesn't regard probability proper.  To summarize the group of related fallacies as I understand them:

Gambler's fallacy: "I've flipped this coin five heads in a row, and so it's due for a tails."
Gambler's fallacy fallacy: "I've flipped this coin five heads in a row; and since the chance of another heads is still 50/50, then that must mean that the chance of flipping six heads in a row is also 50/50."
Inverse gambler's fallacy: "I've just flipped 25 heads in a row; I guess that's not so uncommon after all!" (thanks to comment by @SF)
Your described fallacy: "I've flipped this coin a hundred heads in a row; but if we question the honesty of the coin, that's the gambler's fallacy."

In my view, a particular variant of the anthropic principle in response to fine tuning shares problems with the "gambler's fallacy fallacy" and the one you describe (and maybe even more similarity with the inverse gambler's fallacy).  It goes something like, "As improbable as the fine tuning of the universe might seem, the fact is, we're here, it happened; and if it weren't finely tuned, then we wouldn't be here to talk about it in the first place."  Among other things, this argument seems to dismiss the improbability of fine tuning by looking at the "last event" (our observation of it), hence similar in that sense to the "gambler's fallacy fallacy"; and also seems to dismiss the idea out of hand that the sheer improbability points to something deeper, such as intentional design, similar to yours and the inverse gambler's fallacy.

To add to the mix, there's reverse gambler's fallacy: It just happened therefore it must have happened before / it's not as improbable as we thought, which may be better matching your fine-tuning example.

@SF Good idea, I've edited the answer and "added it to the mix"!
